# Expanding size of WPF labels

Tags: wpf, label

I have several Label controls inside a StackPanel and their width is set to Auto.  However, the width of the label does not extend to utilize 100% of the space available in the StackPanel.  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks.

EDIT: Ok I found out the problem is because I have an AccessText property. So my label is expanding but AccessText is not, even when HorizontalAlignment is set to Stretch.

Answer (score 2):

Auto means that the label will take up just as much space is needed for the text if Horizontal Alignment is center. You will need to set the Horizontal Alignment to stretch for it to take up the entire width.

Comment: The HorizontalAlignment is already set to Stretch.  Ok I found out the problem is because I have an AccessText property.  So my label is expanding but AccessText is not, even when HorizontalAlignment is set to Stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Answer (score 0):

I set following properties and it worked for me.

```
Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```